# Render premultiplied data to transparent PNG file in Java

Tags: java, graphics, png, bufferedimage, premultiplied-alpha

Long story short I have premultiplied Texture. I grab a FrameBuffer, clear it with (0,0,0,0), set the blend mode to `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, and render the Texture. Then I grab the pixels `glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBufferPixels);` and use that:

```
BufferedImage screenshot = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
screenshot.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, argbInts, 0, width);
try {
    ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also have tried `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE` with no change.

The result is this:

[image]

How do I get a nice transparent PNG file out of premultiplied pixel data in OpenGL?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that `setRGB` expects the input to be in non-premultiplied form regardless of the destination image type. So you need to un-multiply the pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc for `BufferedImage.setRGB(...)` says:

> Sets an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB color space, into a portion of the image data.

This means that your input data `argbInts` needs to be in *non-premultiplied form*, regardless of the destination image type. It's of course possible to un-multiply the input pixel data before passing it to the `setRGB` method, but it's a bit tedious for an array with packed ints, so I leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Instead, it is much easier to just change the image to `TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE` and set the pixel data directly with the original premultiplied pixels, like this:

```java
BufferedImage screenshot = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);

// Safe cast for  TYPE_INT_*
int[] imageData = ((DataBufferInt) screenshot.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(); 
System.arraycopy(argbInts, 0, imageData, 0, argbInts.length));

try {
    ImageIO.write(screenshot, "PNG", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And that worked. Wow. Thanks. I never thought to just shove the array in there manually like that